# Ajax call not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that submits to a PHP script with Jquery and Ajax. The PHP script returns some XML. For some reason the Ajax success function is not firing, and the error ones is.

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

My Jquery is as follows

```
$('#submit-excuse').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ws_url = 'http://jacamo.epiphanydev2.co.uk/content/inc/excuse-submit.php?excuse='+$('input#excuse').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: ws_url,
            dataType: "xml",
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('p#response').text('Sending.');
            },
            success: function(xmlIn) {
                results = xmlIn.getElementsByTagName("ReportID");
            },
            error: function() {
                $('p#response').text('Error.');
            }
        });
    });
```

And my PHP script is as follows:

```
$excuse = $_GET['excuse'];

$badwords = array (
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'four',
    'five'
);

if ($excuse == '') {
    $error = 'enter something';
} else {                
    foreach ($badwords as $word) {
        $pos = strpos($excuse, $word);
        if($pos !== false) {
            $passed = false;
        }
    }

    if ($passed !== false) {
        $username = 'xxxxx';
        $password = 'xxxxx';

        $message = $excuse;
        $url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml';

        $curl_handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "status=$message");
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
        $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);

        $passed = 'yes';
    } 

    echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n";
    echo "\t<result>\n";
    echo "\t\t<passed>" . $passed . "</passed>\n";
    echo "\t</result>";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: The 'error' function has three parameters.  Add them to your function and then output them.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery is expecting an xml response back from your query. You need to send the xml header. Try adding before your xml  `header ("content-type: text/xml");` and see if that works

Comment: Perfect, that sorted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AJAX can not be used across different domains, for this, look into [JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

This is how I used it :

JQuery-side :

```
var server = ‘http://www.yoursite.com/path/to/map/’;
var name = ‘Peter’;
var lastname = ‘Marcoen’;
$.getJSON(server+’getData.php?callback=?’,{name:name,lastname:lastname}, function(data) {
alert(data); //Do your thing
});
```

PHP-side :

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
$return = ‘Hello ‘ . $name . ‘ ‘ . $lastname;
echo $_GET['callback'] . ‘(’ . json_encode($return) . ‘)’;
```